# Powershell - Change variable value in a different script

Tags: powershell

I would like to be able to change the value of a variable from a different script.

Let's say I have script X and would like to run some code that changes variable $FirstName from script Y.

This is the code I have in script X, although, I have no idea on how to put them together.

```
Get-Content '\\server\folder\folder2\Scripts\Script.ps1'  
Set-Variable -Name $FirstName -Value "DifferentValue"
```

Would like to change this value in script Y.

```
$FirstName = "SomeValue"
```

Comment: Sorry if not clear enough. I want to change a variable value in script Y by running script X. The reason I am not using get-value and replace is because I will always have different values in the variable. I want to use those variable names as the placeholder and be able to change their values dynamically using script X.

Comment: You likely have  a [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. Depending on what you are really trying to do with the variables, the answer might be something from passing script parameters to saving config into a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to *modify the source code of* a script file in order to change the value of a variable assignment inside it, you can try something like the following, using the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```
@'
# Sample source code of your script, representing the output from (note the -Raw):
#  Get-Content -Raw '\\server\folder\folder2\Scripts\Script.ps1' 
$FirstName = "SomeValue"
# ...
'@ -replace '(?m)(?<=^\s*\$FirstName\s*=\s*")[^"]*', 'DifferentValue'
  # | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 ... to save back to a file, possibly the same.
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/QYlRQm/1).

Note: This is *brittle*, because it relies on the specific quote characters used, the existing value being a *single-line* string, the statement not also being present inside a multi-line comment, ...

As [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) notes, it is worth examining your use case to see if there are better solutions:

> You likely have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777). Depending on what you are really trying to do with the variables, the answer might be something from passing script parameters to saving config into a file